# PROVISION task failed in REQUESTING_CREATE state

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am new in GCP platform and trying to create a simple Data Fusion workflow to load a BigQuery table from a text file that resides in GCS bucket.

The workflow has been deployed successfully. However, while running the workflow, it is failing in step 2 with an error statement

> PROVISION task failed in REQUESTING_CREATE state for program run
>   program_run:default.testing_df.-SNAPSHOT.workflow.DataPipelineWorkflow.5ff986e9-7241-11e9-af46-56bbe5c7844b.

In detailed log below, we have "Required 'compute.firewalls.list' permission for 'projects/mylab-gcp" statement

Below is complete error log for the execution.

> 2019-05-09 10:01:13,945 - DEBUG
>   [provisioning-service-7:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@121] - Executing
>   PROVISION subtask REQUESTING_CREATE for program run
>   program_run:default.testing_df.-SNAPSHOT.workflow.DataPipelineWorkflow.5ff986e9-7241-11e9-af46-56bbe5c7844b.
>   2019-05-09 10:01:16,839 - INFO 
>   [provisioning-service-7:i.c.c.r.s.p.d.DataprocProvisioner@171] -
>   Creating Dataproc cluster
>   cdap-testingdf-5ff986e9-7241-11e9-af46-56bbe5c7844b with system labels
>   {goog-datafusion-version=6_0, cdap-version=6_0_0-1555624816640,
>   goog-datafusion-edition=basic} 2019-05-09 10:01:17,162 - ERROR
>   [provisioning-service-7:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@151] - PROVISION
>   task failed in REQUESTING_CREATE state for program run
>   program_run:default.testing_df.-SNAPSHOT.workflow.DataPipelineWorkflow.5ff986e9-7241-11e9-af46-56bbe5c7844b.
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403
>   Forbidden {   "code" : 403,   "errors" : [ {
>       "domain" : "global",
>       "message" : "Required 'compute.firewalls.list' permission for 'projects/mylab-gcp'",
>       "reason" : "forbidden"   } ],   "message" : "Required 'compute.firewalls.list' permission for 'projects/mylab-gcp'" }     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.cdap.cdap.runtime.spi.provisioner.dataproc.DataprocClient.getFirewallTargetTags(DataprocClient.java:310)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.cdap.cdap.runtime.spi.provisioner.dataproc.DataprocClient.createCluster(DataprocClient.java:155)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.cdap.cdap.runtime.spi.provisioner.dataproc.DataprocProvisioner.createCluster(DataprocProvisioner.java:172)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.cdap.cdap.internal.provision.task.ClusterCreateSubtask.execute(ClusterCreateSubtask.java:43)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.cdap.cdap.internal.provision.task.ProvisioningSubtask.execute(ProvisioningSubtask.java:54)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.cdap.cdap.internal.provision.task.ProvisioningTask.lambda$executeOnce$0(ProvisioningTask.java:123)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.cdap.cdap.common.service.Retries.callWithRetries(Retries.java:183)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.cdap.cdap.common.service.Retries.callWithInterruptibleRetries(Retries.java:257)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.cdap.cdap.internal.provision.task.ProvisioningTask.executeOnce(ProvisioningTask.java:123)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.cdap.cdap.internal.provision.ProvisioningService.lambda$null$16(ProvisioningService.java:559)
>   [na:na]   at
>   io.cdap.cdap.internal.provision.ProvisioningService.callWithProgramLogging(ProvisioningService.java:772)
>   [na:na]   at
>   io.cdap.cdap.internal.provision.ProvisioningService.lambda$null$17(ProvisioningService.java:557)
>   [na:na]   at
>   io.cdap.cdap.common.async.KeyedExecutor$2.run(KeyedExecutor.java:98)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212] 2019-05-09 10:01:17,180 - DEBUG
>   [provisioning-service-7:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@159] - Terminated
>   PROVISION task for program run
>   program_run:default.testing_df.-SNAPSHOT.workflow.DataPipelineWorkflow.5ff986e9-7241-11e9-af46-56bbe5c7844b
>   due to exception.

I can see my root GCP console user along with a Service Account "mylab-bigquery@mylab-gcp.iam.gserviceaccount.com" in IAM console. I have assigned both root account and service account as Owner  along with below additional roles in both account.

BigQuery Admin
Compute Instance Admin (v1)
Compute Network Admin
Compute OS Admin Login
Compute Security Admin
Cloud Data Fusion Admin
Cloud Data Fusion API Service Agent
Owner

However, after doing all these also, still I am getting the same error message "Required 'compute.firewalls.list' permission for 'projects/mylab-gcp"

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look at the Setting up permissions step of creating an instance: https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-instance#setting_up_permissions

This should resolve the issue for you.
Note that this involves adding a new service account to your IAM policy.

Comment: Thank you Ali Anwar. This is a great help and now I an able to spin up cluster and execute my workflow.